# ModemManager accept and start voice call

Tags: linux

I'd like to accept and start voice-calls from ModemManager CLI (mmcli).
It is possible to create a voice-call with

```
mmcli -m 0 --voice-create-call='number=0043xxxxxx'
```

and list the created voice-call with

```
mmcli -m 0 --voice-list-calls                                                                                                                          

Found 1 calls:                                                                                                                                                                   
        /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Call/1 outgoing (unknown)
```

In the [Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/latest/mmcli.1.html) there is mention of a `--start` option which invoked gives me

```
mmcli -m 0 --start           
error: no call was specified
```

This leads to my first question: How to specify a call?

When calling the number and listing voice calls I end up with the result from above. 
Also a simple `--accept` results in `error: no call was specified`.

So how can I accept a voice-call?

The modem has connection to the Internet an can receive and send SMS.
Modem used is the [SIMCom 7600E](https://simcom.ee/modules/lte/sim7600e/). Version of ModemManager is

```
mmcli --version                                                                                                                                         

mmcli 1.8.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the call index from the last command output (seem 1 in your case) via "-o" option:

```
 -o, --call=[PATH|INDEX] Specify Call by path or index. Shows Call information if no action specified.
```

Comment: thanks that helps at least with initiating the outgoing call ...